# activating a HIDDEN menu on DIV tag with a RIGHT MOUSE CLICK using PYTHON SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, contextmenu

I am using Selenium on Python. I was unable to click on a Hidden Menu which seems to activate (make the web element visible) only using a mouse Right Click.

Upon Right Click on a web page icon this element appears on the Elements Inspector:

```
<div role="presentation" class="x-css-shadow" id="ext-element-16" style="box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 0px 0px 6px; z-index: 19000; left: 1163px; top: 596px; width: 162px; height: 218px;"></div>
```

Then underneath it appears also the List of Elements I need to click upon:

```
 <div class="x-menu rptapp-notransparent x-layer x-menu-default x-border-box" style="z-index: 19000; height: 222px; left: 1163px; top: 592px; width: 162px;" role="menu" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="true" id="menu-1899" tabindex="-1" data-componentid="menu-1899"><div id="menu-1899-bodyWrap" data-ref="bodyWrap" class="x-menu-bodyWrap" role="presentation"><div id="menu-1899-body" data-ref="body" class="x-menu-body x-menu-body x-unselectable x-menu-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-menu-body-default" role="presentation" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 160px; height: 220px;"><div role="presentation" class="x-menu-icon-separator x-menu-icon-separator-default" id="ext-element-17">&nbsp;</div><div role="presentation" id="menu-1899-before-scroller" class="x-box-scroller x-box-scroller-top x-box-scroller-menu x-box-scroller-menu-default x-unselectable" style="display:none"></div><div id="menu-1899-innerCt" data-ref="innerCt" role="presentation" class="x-box-inner x-box-scroller-body-vertical x-scroller" style="overflow: hidden; height: 216px; width: 156px;"><div id="menu-1899-targetEl" data-ref="targetEl" class="x-box-target" role="presentation" style="width: 156px;">
```

I tried many different way including this one:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

RunButton = '//*[@id="menu-1899"]'
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, RunButton))).click()`
```

I want to make the menu visible so I can click on items from it.

Step1: this is initial view of the elements on the page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HazxQ.png)

Step2: the I right click on the report element I want to run:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr2dI.png)

Step3: This emenu element appears on the inspector and brings with it the subsequent elements I need to click upon on the Menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmEJ.png)

Comment: You need to post a minimal reproducible example in order for anyone to bee able to help you.

Comment: Hi Barry. Sorry can you pls clarify what is a reproductible example ?

Comment: Enough code to be able to run it and see the error.

Comment: Thanks Barry for the tip. I've now enhanced my post.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the website link. also what you ultimately want to do make it visible or just click on items

Comment: Hi there. I don't have a link as it is from an intranet tool not available to external users. However, I've now enhanced my question above and added for you all the screenshots to show what I see in the inspector and the web page too. So to summarise, on the webpage I need to right click on a report I want to download, then upon right click I get a context menu within which I need to click on the "Run" selection in order to run the report. Using selenium on Python, I couldn't figure out how to click on the Menu and make it visible so I can click on the "Run report" selection.